# Undefined index: action in C:\wamp\www\mysite\header_top.php on line

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Error 1
Undefined index: action in C:\wamp\www\themutual\header_top.php on line 89

On line 89 in headertop.php is:

```
88 <?php 
89  if($_GET['action']!="registerMsg"){?>
90   <span id="login_bar_control2" style="">
91   <a href="#" class="user_registration"   onclick="$('#frgester,#registration_form').show(); $('#reg_username_error,#reg_password_error,#reg_repassword_error,#reg_email_error').html('');" >Registration</a>
```

---

Error 2
Undefined index: UID in C:\wamp\www\themutual\header_top.php on line 128

On line 128 in headertop.php is:

```
127  <!-- My Account link -->
128   <?php if($_SESSION['UID'] > 0 && $_SESSION['usertype']== 'U'){?>
129       <a href="myAccount.php" style="color: #FFFFFF; float: right; margin:10px 0px 7px 5px; padding:0px;">MY ACCOUNT</a>
130   <?php }?>
```

I'm new to php and mysql and just made my first succesful db connection.  I'm trying to troubleshoot a site that i've had created by another developer. The errors above are what i'm getting. I'm using WAMP on windows 7, and the site uses Ajax, and has a calendar on the sidebar which i believe uses .js file.

Comment: you should put the actual errors in your question, not image links

Comment: I think you should not use site that has errors like these. If there are errors, you should fix them and verify the code. If you omit minor errors, you probably omit major ones too, that are not output. Consider repairing the code or if it is ugly written, make one yourself, that you clearly know what is happening. This will be a profit for future.

Comment: @Erik: and what's funny is that it's a screenshot of a screenshot http://images.wikia.com/glee/images/6/6f/We-need-to-go-deeper_inception.jpg or http://piclulz.com/pictures/2008/10/2d6urmc.jpg

Comment: Those errors tell you exactly what is breaking. Go to line 180 of calendar.class.php and then line 128 of the headert_top.php file.

Comment: @Erik: my applications don't produce notices. There is completely no problems in writing such code.

Comment: @Eric - Thanks for that tip.  I will do so.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte - Thank you, I will check those lines and see what may be wrong.

Comment: I've updated the question now to include the actual code, and removed the screenshots.  Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve these notices and warnings, always check that a variable has been initalized by using isset:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']!="registerMsg"){?>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I wonder why it doesn't happen on the live version of the site done by the other developer?  Also, how can i fix this other one:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\themutual\footer.php on line 21

Line 21 is the end of footer.php.  Its just whitespace. Line 20 in the close php tag

Comment: line 20 <?php } ?>

This is the way its ending

Comment: This means that you have a missing } somewhere above line 20 so the PHP gets to the last line and thinks that is where the error is (in this case, line 20) so you need to check all openeing curly brackstes have corresponding closing brackets.

With regard to the errors not happening on the live site, this will be because error reporting is turned off on the live site

Answer (score 0):

as you are getting most of the "undefined offset" errors, so you can disable notice errors from your php.ini file

search "error_reporting" in php.ini file and set value as

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

it will remove all the notice errors

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering if there's any way to detect what the error means?  I can turn them off, but i believe the site will still have functionality problems. So i wanted to figure out the cause of these errors.

Comment: the notice errors which I mentioned are generated when any variable is not initialized